# How to correctly measure the inference time and FLOPs of a model?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn, model-evaluations, metric

For some reason, I can’t find built-in solutions (not really?) in keras and tensorflow, while on the site
https://keras.io/api/applications/ they provide Time (ms) per inference step (CPU), but for some reason they did not describe how they calculated or which function they used.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_flops(model):
    if isinstance(model,(keras.engine.functional.Functional,keras.engine.training.Model)):
        run_meta=tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
        opts=tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
        from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import (convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph)
        inputs=[tf.TensorSpec([1]+inp.shape[1:],inp.dtype) for inp in model.inputs]
        real_model=tf.function(model).get_concrete_function(inputs)
        frozen_func,_=convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(real_model)
        flops=tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=frozen_func.graph,run_meta=run_meta,cmd="scope",options=opts)
        return flops.total_float_ops
```

from https://github.com/tokusumi/keras-flops/blob/master/keras_flops/flops_calculation.py

Comment: Thank you, maybe you also know how to calculate inference time (I want to test and compare h5 and tflite models)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).